# Cherry tree has low shoots off of trunk

Tags: trees, pruning, tree-care, cherries

My sweet cherry has been in for two seasons now so is probably 3 years old.  It is sending low shoots off the trunk. Should I prune those off?[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: A general rule is no branches 4' from the ground, so you can walk around and mow or garden.

Comment: There should be nothing to mow under the tree if you're doing it right, and the tradeoff of starting branches above 4 feet is that it's harder to pick the higher you get, and limits potential harvest if you have a dwarf. Maintaining the mulch under the tree can be done with low branches.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that those low branches are coming from the trunk below a graft, which is a relatively common occurrence (many fruit trees are "dwarfed" via grafting). The tree onto which a fruit tree is grafted will NOT give you the same fruit (if any) as the desirable tree that is grafted onto it, so you must always remove these sprouts in order to keep the undesirable tree from out-competing your fruit tree.

Comment: There are 3 or 4 from below the graft union (can't tell about the 4th for sure from this picture. The rest are above it, and therefore of the desired type.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, you have better eyes than I have :)  I'd still cut everything low off in order to make mowing easier.

Answer (score 2):

To divert this tree's resources away from those lower, trunk branches and instead towards the crown and upward growth, you do have to prune off the low branches. I would even recommend trimming them off all the way to about half of the full height. Good luck with your cherry!